Database experimentation assistant invaild/empty files reading from Azure storage
I am using Database Experimentation Assistant to replay trace files I captured from my production server. The trace files are on Azure Storage account. When I replay it I see the following message
Failed to preprocess, usually, this is a result of an invalid or empty trace / xevent file, please get the detailed information from log file
the log file is not of much help. I can replay the traces from when they are on-premises servers.
I have uninstalled DEA, downloaded the latest and installed it again....still no luck
All help is much appreciated.
I expect the DEA to replay traces from the storage account
